# Delete table row based on listbox selection

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

```
IngID = Me.listbox_material.Value errors with 

IngID = Me.listbox_material.Value = False
```

removed rowsource from listbox

```
'Check for selection, if none made msgbox
If IsNull(Me.listbox_material) Then
    MsgBox "Please make a selection."
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim IngID As Long
Dim strSQL As String

'Get selected records ID value
IngID = Me.listbox_material.Value

'SQL statement
strSQL = "DELETE *FROM[LogExpenses] WHERE ID = " & IngID

'Refresh listbox
Me.listbox_material.Requery
```

When a listbox item is selected and I select the "delete button". A match of the listbox item should be found on table "LogExpenses" and deleted from table.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
DELETE *FROM[LogExpenses]
```

to this:

```
DELETE FROM [LogExpenses]
```

and see if that helps

Comment: I tried all above and I am still receiving the same error msg for IngID = Me.listbox_material.Value. Error = IngID = Me.listbox_material.Value = False.

Answer (score 0):

Your code defines a string-valued variable `strSQL` with a SQL statement, but the code does not subsequently execute this SQL statement.

As such, I might suggest changing this to either:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM [LogExpenses] WHERE ID = " & IngID
```

Or:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM [LogExpenses] WHERE ID = " & IngID
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try following then feedback us.

```
strSQL = "DELETE * FROM [LogExpenses] WHERE ID = '" & IngID & "'"
```

Comment: The error msg I still get from the above code is " IngID =0"